# Dusk to dawn candelabra bulbs in a single fixture

Tags: lighting

How can I stop the 3 dusk to dawn bulbs in a single fixture from interacting with each other?

Comment: There are (or at least were) dumb switches with light  sensors built in, if you don't want a solution that relies on  an internet connection

Comment: You'll need to somehow shield each bulb from seeing any of the light from the other bulbs. But you also need to realize that even if you're successful at that they'll never all turn on or off at the same time - the small tolerances in the electronics will result in slight differences between bulbs light-level detection.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't follow a simpler solution, such as using a remotely-located sensor to control the whole fixture (or multiple fixtures) you'd have to make some sort of internal reflector/shield to prevent each sensor from seeing the other two bulbs - for a 3 bulb fixture I'd envision a sort of Y made from aluminum foil or white plastic/cardboard.